# Google Script: set cell value + prompt message box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on the script below (keep in mind that it's far from done):

```
function Import() {
  var dealCells = getRange('Deals');

  var blank = new Array ("");  

  if (blank.indexOf(dealCells.getValue()) != -1) {
    if (Browser.msgBox('You have not entered all the Deal IDs, do you want to continue anyway?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO) == 'no') {
      Browser.msgBox('Please fill in all the Deal IDs')

      if (blank.indexOf(dealCells.getValue()) == -1) {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Worksheet");
        var cell = sheet.getRange(2,12);
        cell.setValue("IMPORT");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to determine whether or not there is an empty cell in the range A4:A23 in the worksheet 'Newsletter'.

- **If there is an empty cell:** prompt the yes/no message box

  - **If yes:** continue with setting the cell value to 'IMPORT' and finish the script without further actions
  - **If no:** prompt the second message box and finish the script without any further action

Comment: -edited- see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `dealCells` is `A4:A23`:

```
function Import() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Newsletter');
  // Get range values
  var dealCells = sh.getRange("A4:A23").getValues() 
  // Flatten array for `indexOf()`
  var blank = dealCells.join().split(',');

  if (blank.indexOf("") != -1) { // Check if there is a blank cell
     // If a blank cell exist
    var response = Browser.msgBox('You have not entered all the Deal IDs, do you want to continue anyway?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO)

    // Handle the msgBox response
    if (response == "yes") { 
      var value = Browser.msgBox('Please fill in all the Deal IDs')
    } else { //response == no
      ...
    }

  } else { // no blank cell
    ...
  }
...
}
```

**edit** you can also [getRangeByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeByName(String)):

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dealCells = ss.getRangeByName('Deals').getValues();`

Comment: Thanks, that works!
Follow up question though;

Because I'm trying to prompt a Y/N Message box with consequences I need to add another IF. How do I tie that structure together ?

IF there's a blank cell - Message box
IF msgbox = yes - Update Cell L2
IF msgbox = no - Nothing happens

IF no blank cell - Update Cell L2

Comment: Updated code to show some msgBox handling. Just add in the code to `setValue(value)` where you need it or continue on etc

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm